# UTF-8 not working in Spring web app in Tomcat, all is fine in Jetty

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, utf-8

I have a form like this:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Send a Message To Future</legend>
        <label for="fullName">Your Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="fullName" id="fullName">
        <br/>
        <label for="message">Your Message:</label>
        <textarea name="message" rows="3" id="message" style="width: 400px"></textarea>
        <br/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

which is handled in

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postMessage(Model model, MessageToFuture messageToFuture) {
    String fullName = messageToFuture.getFullName();
    String message = messageToFuture.getMessage();
    System.out.println(fullName + " " + message);
    if (fullName.length() == 0 || message.length() == 0) {
        System.out.println("No no no!");
        model.addAttribute("formNotFull", "Please fill in all the fields!");
        return "index";
    } else {
        toFutureRepository.addMessageToFuture(messageToFuture);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

and in web.xml I have:

```
<page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
```

also the header of my jsp has:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

And finally my configuration for Spring:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "biz.tugay.forFuture.web")
public class ServletConfigClass extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver =
                new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

When I post the characters such as 'ğ', if the application is deployed to Tomcat, I am seeing weird characters. But if I run jetty, all is fine.

server.xml for Tomcat has:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

What am I missing?

I tried both with Tomcat 7 and 8.

Comment: Add the `CharacterEncodingFilter` for requests in your `web.xml`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Ah. Thanks a lot. I was going crazy here. But why there is no problem with Jetty? Only with Tomcat?

Comment: No idea, different servers, different implementations different defaults, config etc.

Comment: Actually, there is possibility, everything is right, but System.out.println() is doing it differently. In console output, I also does not see special characters right. But in database it is right. And when I take it from database and use it on HTML page with UTF-8 encoding, it is also ok.

Comment: @M.Deinum Can you provide it as answer so I can accept?